# Tikz Positioning error in Apple silicon Mac

Tags: tikz-pgf, mac

My code got an error in Apple silicon mac. The same code worked in Intel Mac. Here is my beamer slide code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}
\begin{itemize}
\item One item
\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (keyname1) {before overlay};
\onslide<2->{
\node (keyname2) [overlay=of keyname1] {after overlay};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When I typeset, the error message says Package pgfkeys Error: Choice 'of keyname1' unknown in choice key '/tikz/overlay'. I am going to ignore this key.

Could you give me any idea how to fix it?

Edit: I edited the example code so that it does not require graphic files. (Thanks to Roland for first edit it fancy) The above code works on my old Macbook with Mac OS Sierra and MacTex 2015, but not work on M1 Macbook with Mac OS Big Sur and MacTex 2020.

Comment: According to the Ti*k*Z/PGF manual `overlay` is a boolean key, so it is not surprising that `overlay=of keyname1` fails. The more interesting question is probably why this used to work. What is the code supposed to do? Do you remember why you wrote the code like this or where you found this idiom?

Comment: What is overlay doing? i only get the code to wokr when I delete it.

Comment: this looks like a copy & paste error, your key was probably something like `overlay,below=of keyname1`

Comment: I intended to display different graphics in the same position so that when I do clicking, it shows different graphics in the same position in the same slide. So, in the simple example I posted, first shows <graphicfile1> and then shows <graphicfile2>. The code worked on my old MacBook, which was probably on Sierra (so, MacTex was also a quite old version), but the same code shows me error on my New M1 Mac. So, can it be because of the version thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've already told you on the PGF/TikZ bugtracker, this has nothing to do with the Apple Silicon.  The reason why it appeared to have worked on your old computer is because in ancient versions of PGF the `overlay` option was defined as

```
\tikzoption{overlay}[]{\pgf@relevantforpicturesizefalse}
```

With this definition the `overlay` option **ignores any arguments**.  That means that

```
\node (keyname2) [overlay=of keyname1] {after overlay};
```

is completely equivalent to

```
\node (keyname2) [overlay] {after overlay};
```

and you can just use that instead.

If you don't believe, just try

```
\node (keyname2) [overlay=random garbage] {after overlay};
```

on your old computer and observe that nothing changes.

Comment: Okay, so the issue was because of the different versions of PGF. Thanks for the clarification.